How to receive a copy of the outgoing HTTPS traffic from a box and handle it with a custom listening server, while preserving the original one?
to make the subject clearer, I have a closed-source energy meter in my house. The box sends small datapoints out via HTTPS to the manufacturer cloud where I can access it (instant readings and historical graphs). Unfortunately the manufacturer seems to be in great financial troubles and as the could service now works unreliably, none is answering to support requests anymore. Yet I use the energy meter not just for fun, but to monitor a critical appliance (a sink pump that I've to know immediately of if it incurs any anomaly).
Since this energy meter costed a bit and I have some equipment at home (ZyXEL USG firewall, a couple of managed switches, etc) and I am a developer myself, I thought I might do something and learn in the process. My best intent would be:

Get a copy of the box's outgoing traffic forwarded/mirrorerd/redirected to a linux machine I have in the same LAN
Get a server on that linux machine, up&running, capable of receiving and decoding the mirrored packets, and store them in the linux machine itself (I have e.g. a TIG stack there, so InfluxDB would do a great job at it)
Let the original box's outgoing traffic go to the internet and fill in the manufacturer's cloud (in the hope they'll resuscitate, since their service has been great for years). That's why I want a copy of the packets, not a full redirect like tampering with the DNS (unless there's then a way to re-launch the packets to the original destination, if it can work at all)

Now:

I've found a GIT project of a python server that might be capable of reading the HTTPS datapoint packets and have it up&running
I've mirrored the traffic from the energy meter to a NIC on the linux machine via a managed switch, but the packets will of course retain their original SRC and DST addresses, so I still have to figure out how to route the copied packet to my python server (if possible at all). A few iptables PREROUTING attempts have had no luck, perhaps they're not the correct ones.

Not sure if I've been successfully clear enough, but from the description you'll also understand I'm by no means a network admin. I play with toys enough for my simple needs, mostly to learn and become a better professional, but I'm still a newbie on that side.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Basically you're referring to a reverse-proxy.

Thanks for stopping-by @drookie. Could you please expand ?

You probably can't. That's more or less the point of TLS. Unless they have a very broken implementation that accepts any certificate it'll be difficult to MITM the connection. Rewriting destination address is the easy part; a simple destination NAT will mangle the headers in the way you want.

lookup the iptables  -tee option, it may clone traffic, but it won't solve any encryption issues.


capable of receiving and decoding the mirrored packets,
I want a copy of the packets, not a full redirect

That plan is most likely not going to work. Not even the slightest.
Sometimes there are ways to perform an active MITM attack against HTTPS (as mentioned in the comments) – if the device or app accepts a mismatching certificate – but the 'active' part is pretty much mandatory in order for your machine to have the decryption keys for the connection; it needs to actively participate in the key exchange step.
For a purely passive monitor there is no practical way to determine the outcome of DH key exchange out of captured packets, which is indeed the entire premise of SSL/TLS (and SSH, and many other protocols). Key exchange is done separately from certificate verification (or lack thereof), and DH remains equally resistant against passive snooping no matter the setup or protocol.
(Too-small DH parameters can be broken in the same way as small RSA keys, but it's very unlikely that a cloud service would be configured that way.)
So realistically you do need a full redirect – towards some kind of MITM proxy software that would decrypt and reencrypt the traffic (Burp used to be a thing) – and hope that the device doesn't pay attention to the proxy's fake certificate. (But if it does, then you'll need to physically open it up and see if you can find anything in its firmware.)
